# How many words are there of length $7$ are on $\{u,v,w,x,y,z\}$ without the string of letters $xxxx$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

> How many words are there of length $7$ are on $\{u,v,w,x,y,z\}$ without the string of letters $xxxx$?

My idea here is to use inclusion-exclusion. I was thinking of setting up the problem as follows: denoting $C_i$ to be the condition that words of length $7$ are with a string of $x's$ of length $i$ and let $N$ be a function that counts the size of the set.

So $N(C_5)={3 \choose 1}5^2$, since we can place the string $xxxxx$ in only 3 ways. Then with the remaining $2$ spots, we can choose any element from $\{u,v,w,y,z\}$ to place, which gives $5^2$ possibilities. So By the product rule, $N(C_5)={3 \choose 1}5^2$.

So there are: $$\begin{align} N(C^{\complement}) & =|\{\text{words of length $7$ on the set  $\{u,v,w,x,y,z\}$}|-N(C_4)-N(C_5)-N(C_6)-N(C_7) \\ &=6^7-4\cdot5^3-3\cdot5^2-2\cdot5^1-1 \end{align}$$

Am I way off here or do I have the right idea?

Comment: If I understand your idea correctly (you haven't explained it though) In your count of $N(C)$ you are counting $\color{red}{x}xxx???$ and $xxx\color{red}{x}???$ as different strings.

Comment: I don't think your value for N(C) is quite complete.  You need consider there are three positions for the xxxx to occupy and you also have to take into account double counting.  yxxxxzy will be counted twice while uxxxxxy isn't counted at all.  But I'd use your method of subtracting N(c)

Comment: I meant to write $N(C)= \{7 \choose 4}6^3$ but I think this is still wrong, since my logic was basically to choose 4 spots to place the $4$ x's, but I must keep them together.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of subtracting from $6^7$ the number of ‘bad’ strings is fine, as is the idea of counting the bad strings according to the length of the unique string of $x$s making each one bad. (Notice that this would become significantly harder if we were looking at much longer strings, since such strings can be bad more than once.)

Clearly $N(C_7)=1$, as you say, and $N(C_6)=2\cdot5=10$, since the non-$x$ must be one of $5$ letters and can be at either end. $N(C_5)$ is a little trickier.

- You can have $axxxxxb$, where neither $a$ nor $b$ can be $x$; there are $5^2=25$ strings of this type.
- You can have $xxxxxab$ or $baxxxxx$, where $a\ne x$, and $b$ can be any of the $6$ letters; there are $2\cdot5\cdot6=60$ strings of this type.

Thus, $N(C_5)=25+60=85$.

I’ll leave you to try to fix the calculation of $N(C_4)$ using similar ideas; I’ve left the answer in the spoiler-protected block below so that you can check yourself.

> $2\cdot5\cdot6^2+2\cdot5^2\cdot6=660$.